# TFS 2015 - Task board and kanban board state names

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, kanban

Based on requirements, for user story kanban board, we added following columns

- TODO
- Development
- System Test
- Done

In Task dashboard, for given user story, all tasks are in swim lanes accordingly to its state.

States which are shown in task board for user story is not what we have added as customized columns and it shows as

- New
- Active
- Resolved
- Remove
- Closed
  [image: Screen shot]

This is confusing for the team, is there any way i can customized this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are customizing the current Kanban board column assignment of the work item, which Reference name=`System.BoardColumn`. For example the default value is: *New, Active,Resolved, Closed* in a Agile process.

However states which are shown in task board for user story is using to track the progress of user stories. It's a workflow progression. More details about this, you could refer this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380634(v=vs.110).aspx#Workflow). There are totally different concepts for each other. So, which you got is the expect phenomenon.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for quick reply, What i do in kanban is also workflow progression, right ? As when i move user story from Todo (i.e. New) to Development (i.e. Active), same is reflected in state of user story in Task dashboard, So is it feasible to show column name what i defined in kanban in task dashboard against given user story ? Or altogether if in can modify workflow and change state names what i have on kanban dashboard is more appropriate?

Comment: @ManishJoisar  To customize the workflow, follow these two steps:
1.Modify the WORKFLOW section of the WIT definition as described in this topic. 2. Modify the process configuration to map new workflow states to metastates. This second step is required when you change the workflow for a WIT that appears on an Agile tool page. You could update the XML definition for a WIT with on-premises  TFS.  Detail steps please refer this topic: [Change the workflow for a work item type](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/change-workflow-wit#update-the-xml-definition-for-a-wit)